# GTM/Javascript - Search up DOM to find Parent h2

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

What i'm trying to accomplish is to find if the click element has a `h2` tag, if not, then move to the parent and perform the same check until a value is found and return the value.

When the href link is clicked, I need Google Tag Manager to set the parent `h2` text as the variable so it can be used in Event Tracking.

*Edit: I cannot use jQuery code for this sorry.*

Here's an extract of the HTML code;

```html
<div id="contentRight" class="right">
  <div class="widget blue">
      <h2>Link Title</h2>
    <div style="clear:both;">
      <a href="https://www.websitelink.com" class="buttonOrange" target="_self" >Find out more 
        <i class="fa   fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After spending a few hours looking at various post all over the internet, I currently have a mash up of code that isn't working;

```
function(){    
  var element = {{Click Element}};
    while(element.querySelector('h2').innerText === undefined);
 {
     element = element.parentNode;
 }
 return element.querySelector('h2').innerText;}
```

Can anyone shed some light on what i'm doing wrong, or provide some suggestion how this may be done?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be going about it in an awkward way, but if I'm understanding your ask, what you are after is the `h2` text for any link that is a child of that element. So, assuming you have jQuery loaded, t would require a simple custom JS tag that would look similar to this:

```
function(){
   var ce = {{Click Element}};
   return $(ce).closest('#contentRight').find('h2').text().trim()
}
```

That should return the title for the link, ie. "Link Title".

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but unfortunately jQuery won't be used in this instance. Is there a JavaScript alternative to the jQuery code?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is closed, but the links provided should guide you on how to implement the custom JS without jQuery.